# Ajax call contains data that needs to load first

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on a Ajax call by which i am getting data from the server and want to use the response in the view. The data i need at first to be used how can i load it first before everything else ... do anyone know any solution for this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var data = {
          "page" : "0",
          "size" :"10"
       }
  var totalPages = 0;
 $(document).ready( function () {
    alert("Datatable Start");
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/getcomp",
     data:data,
     contentType:'application/json',
     success: function (data) {
         totalPages = data.totalPages;
         handleData(totalPages);
         alert("Inside Success" +totalPages);
   }
 });
    // ajax call end here
    function handleData( responseData ) {

        // Do what you want with the data
        alert("in function callback"+ responseData);
    }
 });


 </script>
```

Comment: can you elaborate more with your problem ? currently what happen when you called your function ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `async:false` in your ajax request. i.e.:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/getcomp",
     data:data,
     contentType:'application/json',
     async:false,
     success: function (data) {
         totalPages = data.totalPages;
         handleData(totalPages);
         alert("Inside Success" +totalPages);
   }
 });
```

Comment: what happen with this ....  then this will not server the purpose of getting data from the server side.

Comment: this will actually make this a synchronous call, so first ajax call will complete and then flow will move further where you can use response data from call

Comment: But this is not calling the method at server side... sorry it is not useful